# Redux Reducer - Filter array based on id then change key/value pair

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of comments which I want to filter on based on an ID and change a specific key/value pair. My console log function returns the correct item in the array but I'm unsure of the correct syntax for taking the result of the .filter function and changing the 'liked' key from 'false' to 'true'. I am able to use the spread operator if it is suitable in this situation.

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';
import initialState from './initialState';

export default function commentReducer(state = initialState.comments, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.ADD_COMMENT_LIKE_SUCCESS:
      const content = Object.assign({}, state);
      const likedComment = content.data.filter(comment => (
        comment.id === action.commentId
      ));
      console.log(likedComment[0]);
      break;

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

The comments object look like this:

```
"data":{  
      "data":[  
         { id: '', comment: '', liked: false },
         { id: '', comment: '', liked: false },
         { id: '', comment: '', liked: false },
         { id: '', comment: '', liked: false }
      ],
      "cursor":"CkUKEQoEZGF0ZRIJCNrwhcWhvdUCEixqFGRldn5kZXZlbG9wbWVudC0xMzAwchQLEgdDb21tZW50GICAgLSe_-cKDBgAIAE=",
      "more":false,
      "count":4
   },
```

Comment: how does your `initialState` look like ?

Comment: Edited my question to include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the **filter function with correct syntax**, although your reducer should return all the comments with that particular comment with liked key value pair as true, this how you can go ahead **using the map function for the same**.

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';
import initialState from './initialState';

export default function commentReducer(state = initialState.comments, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.ADD_COMMENT_LIKE_SUCCESS:
      const content = Object.assign({}, state);
      content.data =  content.data.map(comment => {
                      const newObj = {...comment};
                      if(newObj.id === action.commentId)
                      { 
                            newObj.likeKey = true;
                      }
                      return newObj;
      }); 
     console.log(content);
     return content;   
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Map functin will return all the comments you have till now, with that particular comment object changed. Hope this helps.

Comment: This changes the key value pair but unfortunately it returns just the array of comments instead of the full comment object (therefore removing the 'cursor', 'more', and 'count' keys).

Comment: I have updated the code in anwser, i think now it will return the complete object, does it?

Answer (score 0):

I would use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of filter since it always return only one item.

I'm not completely sure about how you splitted your state, but I can suggest to return like:

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';
import initialState from './initialState';

export default function commentReducer(state = initialState.comments, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.ADD_COMMENT_LIKE_SUCCESS:
      const otherComments = state.data;
      const likedComment = state.data.find(comment => (
        comment.id === action.commentId
      ));
      const index = state.data.indexOf(likedComment);

      return {
          ...state,
          data: {
              [
                  ...otherComments.slice(0, index),
                  { ...likedComment, liked: true }, //Override properties here
                  ...otherComments.slice(index + 1)
              ]
          }
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

There's no need for copy content from state, since I'm not modifying state.

Basically I'm:

1. **Copying** `state` and overriding `data` key with ...
2. A **copy** of all comments and concatenating with my **copy** `likedComment`, but with overriden data

Comment: This does change my key value nicely, but when liking a comment it then adds that comment to the end of the array (e.g. if I like the 2nd of 4 comments my Redux state changes so that the 2nd comment is now at the 4th position)

Comment: @GuerillaRadio You can't add a Index or CreatedAt properties, so we can sort it?

Comment: @GuerillaRadio Just think better... We can get index and conserve it with slice. Edited my code, try it.